# devServer proxy in vue.config.js incorrectly mapping urls

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vuejs3

I'm working on a vue/cli 3 project. My `vue.config.js` is

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? '/admin/' : '/',
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/serveradmin': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/serveradmin',
      },
      "/assets/*": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080/assets",
        logLevel: 'debug',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Using `curl -v -X "HEAD" http://localhost:8081/assets/css/main.css`, I get a 404. The console shows:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8081/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.1.155:8081/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.

[HPM] HEAD /assets/css/main.css -> http://localhost:8080/assets
```

I've tried fiddling with pathRewrite, and it doesn't change the results. Changing the proxy key to `"/assets"` doesn't make any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `target` property should be the base URL to which the original path is appended. With your current config, the request would be for `http://localhost:8080/assets/assets/css/main.css` (notice the two `assets`).

Remove the `/assets` suffix from your target URL:

```js
// target: "http://localhost:8080/assets",
target: "http://localhost:8080",
```